# Facebook v4 login gives 503 error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I hope someone helps me with this puzzle.

I tested facebook login v4 on my localhost where it works just fine,
at first it also worked on my live server, but for a mysterious reason it no longer does.

When on my live server (http://www.zenmony.com/test.php) I click the OAuth link, and for some reason I get a 503 error, and facebook throws no exceptions, so there is no way to debug.

here is my code:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '738781846169261','*******ac965af67d8979be972655c');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.zenmony.com/test.php');
//$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/test.php');

if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
        try {
            if ( !$session->validate() ) {
                    $session = null;
                }
            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                $session = null;
                print_r($e);
                exit;
            }
        }

        if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {        
            try {
                $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
            } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
                print_r($ex);
                exit;
            } catch( Exception $ex ) {
                print_r($ex);
                exit;
            }
        }

        // see if we have a session
        if (isset($session))
        {
            // save the session
            $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
            $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
            $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
            $response = $request->execute();
            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

            echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            // show login url
            $link = $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) );//&display=popup
            echo "<a href=\"$link\">LINK</a>";
        }
```

Apparently the scipt goes as far as `$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();` but throws no exceptions and I have the 503 error code.

Just in case, here are my facebook application settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please, need any help!

Comment: Is the 503 coming from your server (ie, you see it in your browser) or from Facebook? If the response is from your server, check the web server error logs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In the logs I have: 2014-09-29 22:59:29.823 [NOTICE] [106.188.229.58:51740-0#zenmony.com] Max retries has been reached, 503!
2014-09-29 22:59:29.823 [NOTICE] [106.188.229.58:51740-0#zenmony.com] oops! 503 Service Unavailable
2014-09-29 22:59:29.823 [NOTICE] [106.188.229.58:51740-0#zenmony.com] Content len: 0, Request line: 'GET /test.php?code=AQDUEJDw...CnZEzn-RonDr3&state=b43ec118cfc510ff7bc98548f2c9b727 HTTP/1.1'

Comment: It seems like a litespeed cookie size problem. I will try contacting Litespeed for a solution.